# postfix queue not getting cleared instantaneously

Tags: email, queue, postfix-mta

I have over 1 lakh emails in postfix mail queue and they are getting cleared very slowly. Even if I restart the server, the rate of mail delivery does not improve. The mails are piling up and the total disk usage increases because of this. The mails are sent to postfix from a java web application which has the logic for sending mails to its users on daily basis. Also the mails that are in the queue have arrived 15 days back and some of them still not sent.
I am a newbie in postfix. Can anyone please help?
Any config setting you need, please let me know as I do not have the root rights and would need to get it from the higher authorities to investigate this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should look into postfix flush command.

Answer (score 0):

First: Postfix already sends out mail as fast as it can.
Second: no need to flush a clogged toilet

Please check the logs for a few mails mail stuck in the queue; the **mailq** output shows you

```
   3ttshY72rszG48m     18875 Wed Jan  4 13:53:01 ffc6+bncBDQKF66M6YGBBNP4WPBQKGQEXXXE2QA@sender
                                           localpart@recipientdomain.de
```

In this example "3ttshY72rszG48m" is the queue-id. Use **grep** to find all log entries regarding a particular, stuck email and check why the mail is not being delivered (status= field). Also check the delays= value --
the format of the "delays=a/b/c/d" logging is as follows:

- a = time from message arrival to last active queue entry
- b = time from last active queue entry to connection setup
- c = time in connection setup, including DNS, EHLO and STARTTLS
- d = time in message transmission

Find out which value is dominating.